# Any grammatical patterns for using the word, 'all', in "all (last night/yesterday/today/next month)"

Tags: sentence-construction, time

In this question, I am focusing on the word, **'all'**, combined with the following phrases.
I have made up the sets of similar examples below:

> 1. a) *"I had a headache **all last night**."* (correct)
>    b) *"I had a headache **all night last night**."*
>    c) *"I had a headache **for all of last night**."* (correct)

> 2. a) *"I was here **all yesterday**."*
>    b) *"I was here **all day yesterday**."* (correct)
>    c) *"I was here **for all of yesterday**."* (correct)

> 3. a) *"I'm here **all today**."*
>    b) *"I'm here **all day today**."* (correct)
>    c) *"I'm here **for all of today**."* (correct)

> 4. a) *"I'll stay here **all next month**."* (correct)
>    b) *"I'll stay here **all month next month**."*
>    c) *"I'll stay here **for all of next month**."* (correct)

I spent a lot of time talking to my non-native English speaking friends about my sentences. They picked the ones that they thought were correct. I marked their choices as correct. There are two correct answers in each set.

I'm wondering if there is a grammatical pattern for the correct ones. I'm very confused about this. Do you think my friends' answers are correct?

Comment: I would not have marked any of the alternatives as incorrect, though I would not use 2a or 3a.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that all of the ones you have listed as "correct" are grammatically valid and might be said by a fluent or native speaker. Of the ones you have not so labeled:

> 1b) "I had a headache all night last night." [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

I find 1B perfectly valid, and I think it would be more usual than 1C

> 2b) "I was here all day yesterday." [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

I find 2b to be valid and reasonably natural, although less likely than 2a or 2c.

> 3a) "I'm here all today." [image: Red X for "do not use"]

I can't spot any actual error in 3a, but it feels awkward to me an i would not say this. I might well use 3b or 3c.

> 4b) "I'll stay here all month next month."

I can't see anything wrong with 4b and I would understand it, but I doubt that I would say it. I suspect the repetition of "month" feel awkward. I would add that I find 4C to flow better than 4A, but that is a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and detailed explanation. I really appreciate it.